# Alternatives to IBM Daeja viewONE virtual

Tags: open-source, viewer

I'm searching for alternatives to IBM Daeja viewONE virtual. You know, for view, annotate, zoom, magnify, scroll, pan, rotate, and print images. That allow edit the mayor amount of document extensions as posible. If it's open source, better. Any suggestions ?

Thanks!!